# Spring Security with hibernate : hasRole() is not working in config

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security for my Spring + Hibernate project.

But the hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN') that i write in the intercept-url tag is not working.

Please find the config that i have done below.

**springSecurity.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')" />
        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            login-processing-url="/loginCheck" password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsServices">
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

I am using the following auth provider

```
public class MyUserDetailsServices implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userDao.findByEmail(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not found");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);

    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User buildUserForAuthentication(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (Role userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRoleName()));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }

    public UserDao getUserDao() {
        return userDao;
    }

    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

}
```

The The above code is working fine. I am able to get the correct role and buildUserForAuthentication() method is returned with the SUPER_ADMIN role added in the authorities.

But still the hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN') is not working. I am not able to access the page http://127.0.0.1:8080/myproj/admin. The user is getting authenticated and logged in. But the above url is getting redirected to /403 (Access Denied).

Am i missing something? Please help.!

Answer (score 2):

The `hasRole` is working well. What is not working in your code is your wildcard on your springSecurity.xml.
Change this

`<intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')" />`

to

`<intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('SUPER_ADMIN')" />`

Not sure why and how, but spring seems to add a leading slash why validating your url.

so having `/admin/**` will have the same effect as your intended `/admin**`.

Comment: Hi @storm_blaster, I have tried that as well but unfortunately that is also not working. :(

Comment: It should be working. Look, to rule out if it is the pattern which is causing the error, you could change the access method to isAuthenticated() for example. if you dont get the 403, it means there is a problem with your Role. Could be checking for ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Adding a 'ROLE_' in front of SUPER_ADMIN worked. I am assuming that every spring role should start with 'ROLE_'. Didn't expert that to be a mandatory thing. So never tried that option. :)

Comment: there is setting for that, to set that prefix. can't remember which one, have to look for it in the doc. but i definitely read about it there.

Answer (score 0):

Got this rectified by adding 'ROLE_' to the rolename. Made it as ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN and it started working. I am assuming that every role should be prefixed with 'ROLE_' for spring security to work properly.

Thanks @storm_buster for the tip. :)

Comment: If storm_buster helped you solve this, would it be a nice gesture to upvote or accept (tick) his or her answer?